# Optimal locations for vertices of a polygon with given area

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I want to find the optimal locations for vertices of a polygon (with area A) such that it is as close as possible to the desired area A'. Please note that the vertices need not be fixed at their initial locations. I'm looking for an optimization algorithm that looks at the change in the area of the sub-triangle associated with that vertex to minimize the area difference A-A'.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are asking.  What is the input?  What is the desired output?  What is given, and what are you free to choose?  Are you say, given $A$, find a polygon with area $A$?  If so, that seems trivial.  However, that doesn't seem to fit your last sentence.  Where did the sub-triangles come from?  As it stands, the question doesn't seem answerable, as it's hard to tell what you're asking.  Please edit the question to clarify what you problem you are trying to solve, and this can be considered to be re-opened.  You might also consider adding an example.